# Timeout when uploading images

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am currently testing Tridion 2011 and am having problems creating multimedia components with uploaded content (as opposed to external).

I fill out the title, schema, multimedia type, select a file from my system then click save. I get a `Saving item...` information message then approximately 30 seconds later I will receive a `The wait operation timed out` message.

There doesn't appear to be any error messages in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\log` directory. Looking at the event viewer I see the following information relating to the save action

```
Unable to save Component (tcm:4-738361).
The wait operation timed out

Error Code:
0x8004033F (-2147220673)

Call stack:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean,Action`1)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean,Action`1)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject,Boolean,Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior,SqlCommand,SqlDataReader,BulkCopySimpleResultSet,TdsParserStateObject,Boolean&)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader,RunBehavior,String)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,Boolean,Int32,Task&,Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,String,TaskCompletionSource`1,Int32,Task&,Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1,String,Boolean,Int32,Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.SetBinaryContent(Int32,Stream)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.ItemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IItemDataMapper.SetBinaryContent(Stream,TcmUri)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.SetBinaryContent(BinaryContent)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.OnSaved(SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save()
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.VersionedItemFacade.UpdateAndCheckIn(UserContext,String,Boolean,Boolean)
XMLState.Save
Component.Save
```

I already have my timeout settings in the Content Manager Snap-In set to high values (more than 10 minutes) due to [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316052/tridion-event-system-timeout).

The `BINARIES` table in the Content Manage Database is 25GB if that helps.

Any ideas? Thanks.

### Edit 1

Following suggestions from Bart Koopman, my DBA has rebuilt the indexes but does not reckon the Transaction log has any impact on performance. The problem persists.

### Edit 2

I have just found more details of the error

```
Unable to save Component (tcm:0-0-0).
Timeout expired.
The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS_UPDATEBINARYCONTENT".EDA_ITEMS_UPDATEBINARYCONTENT
```

After taking a look at this procedure it looks like the following statement could be the root cause

```
SELECT 1 FROM BINARIES WHERE ID = @iBINARY_ID AND CONTENT IS NULL
```

I execute it manually with @iBINARY_ID as -1 and after 2 minutes it still hasn't completed. I assume that when I insert a new multimedia component the query will be something similar (i.e. the id will not exist in the table).

The BINARIES table currently has a `NON-CLUSTERED` Primary Key. Maybe the solution would be to change this to a `CLUSTERED` Primary Key? However, I assume it is NON-CLUSTERED for a reason.

Comment: How big is your item, can you try with small item?

Comment: The image I am currently trying to upload is only 4kb

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just had a response from SDL customer support. Apparently this is a known issue related to statistics and the chosen query plan.

Running the following statement manually from SQL Server Management Studio fixes the problem (it didn't even need to complete for me)

```
SELECT 1 FROM BINARIES WHERE ID = -1 AND CONTENT IS NULL
```

Hope this helps someone else out!

Comment: This fixed my issue once, but now it has come up again.  Does anyone else have an idea of how to fix this permanently so I don't have to keep running this query to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Timeouts on database operations are usually an indication of a misconfiguration or a lack of maintenance. By increasing the timeout you are just working around the problem rather than solving it.

With a binaries table that big you will want to make sure you have proper database setup with data files that are separated from your log files (separated on different physical partitions/disks) and possibly even multiple data files on multiple physical partitions to take advantage of performance gains.

Next to that you will want to assure that the standard database maintenance is performed daily/hourly. Things like backing up and truncating the transaction log every hour will greatly improve your database performance (on MS SQL Server a transaction log of more than 1GB slows the database down drastically, you should always try to keep it below that size through timely backup/trucate). Updating statistics and rebuilding indexes is also something you should not forget on a regular basis.

Comment: Could it be that the live 5.3 db is setup/maintained differenty? I usually come across these issues on dev servers which are not maintained, where I would expect a live db to have a DBA watching over it.

Comment: I have talked to my DBA and they suggest that the problem is something other than the database as they have now done some performance tuning.